# Hiding reports from specific user

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have made a *drill down* report which contains 5 *subreports*, all of them are connected using *Hyperlink* section.

I want users only to view the main *drill down* report, I mean first label of *drill down*. If I set **Execute Only** permission for the **ROLE_USER**, that particular report is not working, throwing errors like *`Access Denied`*.

Can anybody tell me how can I hide reports as well input controls attached to that.

Answer (score 0):

Drill down reports must have linking to the upper level reports and those reports may have different permissions then **"Execute only"**. The permissions set are inherited from the above level of reports and hence the error.Please check if you have the right permissions for the folders or upper level reports.Also,refer to the documentation for the permission settings.Authentication and Authorization are pretty well documented and good to get started.
Hope that helps!!