# How to restrict to view some sub-reports based on user role

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding reports from specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705747/hiding-reports-from-specific-user)

I have a master report with several *subreports* in it.

How can I restrict users based on their roles to view some of the *subreports* in *JasperReports/JasperReports Server*?

Comment: There is no role-based model in *JasperReports*. You can ask this question only in context of using *JR Server*.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK .I am actually not getting any direction to solve this issue.Do we have something (some parameter or anything) by which we can access the roles of the user .Any help would be highly appreciated